# Simple Nick Namer

Tags: java, strings

This is very simple: the user inputs his/her name, the program then truncates it on a consonant at a specified position, if possible if not it will truncate it on a vowel. It then adds an extension from a list of extensions to make the complete nickname and displays it.

```
 /**
 * @author              :KyleMHB
 * Project Number       :0001
 * Project Name         :Nick Namer
 * IDE                  :NETBEANS
 * Goal of Project      -
 * Use a given name and create a nick name using an extension.
 */
package nicknamer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

```
public class NickNamer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = getName("Enter your name!");
    List<String> nickExtension =  Arrays.asList("anosorus","asaur","asaurus","onosorus","apede");
    String output=getRandomNick(truncateName(word,"AEIOUaeiou",2),nickExtension);
    showOutput(word+" your Nickname is "+output);
}
```

```
private static String getName(String prompt){
    String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt);
    return input;
}
```

This method below is meant to truncate the name on a consonant, at a position of my choosing (via the position `int`) or until it finds one after that position. E.g.: James becomes Jam and Jaemes becomes Jaem.

```
private static String truncateName(String word,String vowels, int position) {
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    String output;
    int iterate=position;
    while(iterate!=word.length()){
    if(vowels.indexOf(wordArray[iterate]) < 0){
        return word.substring(0,iterate+1);  
    }else{iterate++;}
    }
    return word.substring(0,position);
}
```

```
private static String getRandomNick(String word,List nickExtension) {
    Random r = new Random();
    return word + nickExtension.get (r.nextInt(nickExtension.size()));
}
```

```
private static void showOutput(String output) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output);
}
}
```

Comment: Why is this used? `nickExtension.size() - 0`

Comment: `nickExtension.size() - 0` is the range in which the random number must be generated so it doesn't try access a list entry that doesn't exist.

Comment: You don't need to subtract 0 to anything.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. Thank you. Will change it now.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static String getName(String prompt){
    String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt);
    return input;
}
```

I like what you've done here.  But I would rename the method to `getInput(String prompt)` since you've made it reusable.  You can get anything from the user with this method, since you're passing in the `prompt`!  I would also make it a one-liner instead of storing the variable for no reason.

i.e.,

```
private static String getInput(String prompt) {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
}
```

Now in this method ...

```
private static String getRandomNick(String word,List nickExtension) {
    Random r = new Random();
    return word + nickExtension.get (r.nextInt(nickExtension.size() - 0));
}
```

The `Random` should probably be a constant in your overarching class.  Meaning it should be `private static final Random RANDOM = new Random()`.  There's no need to create a new object each time you want to generate a number.

Even if you wanted to do it this way, there would be no reason to store it in a variable.

Also, why are you doing `nickExtension.size() - 0`?  Get rid of the `- 0` since it does nothing.

```
private static String truncateName(String word,String vowels, int position) {
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    String output;
    int iterate=position;
    while(iterate!=word.length()){
    if(vowels.indexOf(wordArray[iterate]) < 0){
        return word.substring(0,iterate+1);  
    }else{iterate++;}
return word.substring(0,position);
}
```

This entire method is really confusing.  It looks like you're trying to return a substring of the name when you hit a vowel?  But this would do the opposite and actually only continue as long as it finds vowels, since `indexOf()` will return `-1` (and thus be less than 0) if the letter is not present.  So as soon as you hit a consonant, your method will return.  If this is actually what you were trying to achieve, then I don't get it.

I would rewrite the whole thing.  Also, since the vowels are a constant and would never change, I would put that at the top as a constant field as well: `private static final List<Character> VOWELS = Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U');`  There's also no need to pass in the `position` either, since it's a constant.

```
private static String truncateName(String name) {
    char[] characters = name.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 3; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if(!VOWELS.contains(Character.toLowerCase(characters[i]))) {
            return name.substring(0, i + 1);
        }
    }
    return name.substring(0, 3);
}
```

Throw in some general renaming of variables and methods to be more descriptive, cleanup of tabs, indentation, and spaces, clearing of unused variables ...

**AND IN THE END, THERE WAS CODE**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NickNamer {

    private static final Random RNG = new Random();
    private static final List<String> NICKNAME_EXTENSIONS = Arrays.asList("anosaurus", "asaur", "asaurus", "onosaurus", "apede");
    private static final List<Character> VOWELS = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = getInput("Enter your name!");
        String output = getRandomNickname(truncateName(name));
        displayOutput(name + ", your nickname is " + output + "!");
    }

    private static String getInput(String prompt){
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
    }

    private static String truncateName(String name) {
        char[] characters = name.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 3; i < characters.length; i++) {
            if(!VOWELS.contains(Character.toLowerCase(characters[i]))) {
                return name.substring(0, i + 1);
            }
        }
        return name.substring(0, 3);
    }

    private static String getRandomNickname(String word) {
        return word + NICKNAME_EXTENSIONS.get(RNG.nextInt(NICKNAME_EXTENSIONS.size()));
    }

    private static void displayOutput(String output) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah it returns on a consonant, so James would be Jam. I dont want the extra vowel.
The position is something I have so I can set at what char it starts looking for a consonant.
And for the random isnt it better to only create it when needed? I was always taught to be efficient and not have more variables initialized than I needed.

Comment: In `Arrays.asList("anosaurus, asaur, asaurus, onosaurus, apede")`, don't you mean `Arrays.asList("anosaurus", "asaur", "asaurus", "onosaurus", "apede")`?

Comment: @KyleMHB Gotcha.  Makes sense.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Thanks, some nifty things I missed.
I changed my `getName` `return` to this `return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);`
And deleted a `String output` that never got used. 
But I will still pass position because if I want to change it I only have to change it in one place.

As for the static variables I like to keep them localized to methods if I can.

Comment: @KyleMHB Well, you *definitely* shouldn't be creating a `new Random()` each time you want to make a nickname.  The others you can just pass around from `main()` if you really want to, but it's somewhat poor design practice.  And passing in the position makes sense, depending on what the API would be used for in the future, etc.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Obviously as you say its not a good idea but I dont know why... Could you please explain? Im still new to this.

Comment: @KyleMHB So it's for efficiency purposes.  Every time that method executes, it will create a new object (allocate memory for it, run through all its constructor code, etc.) then garbage collect it.  That's actually the majority of the work load of the method, as you have it written, and you get absolutely no benefits from it.  Sure, efficiency is trivial with such a small program, but these are the things you should think about early on as you're learning so that you can make good decisions when you develop something bigger.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Thank you for clarifying. I was under the impression that have the variables preloaded into memory in a large program would be detrimental as they take up space when it could be free. That was probably true 10 years ago!